# SolrHealthIndicator without deprecated CompositeHealthIndicator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr

I've tried to upgrade Spring Boot to 2.2.4.RELEASE version. Everzthing if fine exept problem with `CompositeHealthIndicator` which is deprecated.

I have this bean method

```
@Autowired
private HealthAggregator healthAggregator;

    @Bean
public HealthIndicator solrHealthIndicator() {
    CompositeHealthIndicator composite = new CompositeHealthIndicator(
            this.healthAggregator);
    composite.addHealthIndicator("solr1", createHealthIndicator(firstHttpSolrClient()));
    composite.addHealthIndicator("solr2", createHealthIndicator(secondHttpSolrClient()));
    composite.addHealthIndicator("querySolr", createHealthIndicator(queryHttpSolrClient()));
    return composite;
}

private CustomSolrHealthIndicator createHealthIndicator(SolrClient source) {

    try {
        return new CustomSolrHealthIndicator(source);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to create helthCheckIndicator for solr client instance.", ex);
    }
}
```

That registers HealthIndicator for 3 instances of SOLR (2 indexing, 1 for query). Everything worked fine until Spring Boot update. After update the method `CompositeHealthIndicator.addHealthIndicator` is not present, the whole class is marked as Deprecated.

The class which is created in createHealthIndicator is like this:

```
    public class CustomSolrHealthIndicator extends SolrHealthIndicator {

    private final SolrClient solrClient;

    public CustomSolrHealthIndicator(SolrClient solrClient) {
        super(solrClient);
        this.solrClient = solrClient;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {

        if (!this.solrClient.getClass().isAssignableFrom(HttpSolrClient.class)) {

            super.doHealthCheck(builder);
        }

        HttpSolrClient httpSolrClient = (HttpSolrClient) this.solrClient;
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(httpSolrClient.getBaseURL())) {
            return;
        }

        super.doHealthCheck(builder);
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to transform the old way how to register the instances of SOLR i want to check if they are up or down at Spring Boot version 2.2.X?

**EDIT:**
 I have tried this:

```
@Bean
public CompositeHealthContributor solrHealthIndicator() {

    Map<String, HealthIndicator> solrIndicators = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    solrIndicators.put("solr1", createHealthIndicator(firstHttpSolrClient()));
    solrIndicators.put("solr2", createHealthIndicator(secondHttpSolrClient()));
    solrIndicators.put("querySolr", createHealthIndicator(queryHttpSolrClient()));

    return CompositeHealthContributor.fromMap(solrIndicators);
}

private CustomSolrHealthIndicator createHealthIndicator(SolrClient source) {

    try {
        return new CustomSolrHealthIndicator(source);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to create healthCheckIndicator for solr client instance.", ex);
    }
}
```

The CustomSolrHealthIndicator has no changes against start state.

But I cannot create that bean. When calling `createHealthIndicator` I am getting **NoClassDefFoundError**

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Have you looked at the suggested replacement? Spring is usually very good about marking intended replacements when deprecating functionality.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/CompositeHealthContributor.html

Comment: Sorry, I see you've already looked at it. Not sure why you need to override it. Just pass in a map of your `SolrHealthIndicator`s.

Comment: Well, thats cause im implementing that interface.

Comment: I've edited my question, the main problem is when i want to create a bean, I am getting NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` What class is not found? You probably are just missing an updated dependency.

Comment: Yep, you are right i had to upgrade solr to latest version 8.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can just use [CompositeHealthContributor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/CompositeHealthContributor.html). It's not much different from what you have already. It appears something like this would work. You could override the functionality to add them one at a time if you'd like, also, which might be preferable if you have a large amount of configuration. Shouldn't be any harm with either approach.

```
@Bean
public HealthIndicator solrHealthIndicator() {
    Map<String, HealthIndicator> solrIndicators;
    solrIndicators.put("solr1", createHealthIndicator(firstHttpSolrClient()));
    solrIndicators.put("solr2", createHealthIndicator(secondHttpSolrClient()));
    solrIndicators.put("querySolr", createHealthIndicator(queryHttpSolrClient()));
    return CompositeHealthContributor.fromMap(solrIndicators);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I have tried your approach (my actual state is after the EDIT: section of my answer. The problem is when i want to create a bean, I am getting NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: EDIT: I had to update the SOLR dependencies too, there was some Exception objects that were not present in the previous version of SOLR I´ve been used.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deprecated CompositeHealthIndicator#addHealthIndicator use constructor with map:

```
@Bean
public HealthIndicator solrHealthIndicator() {

    Map<String, HealthIndicator> healthIndicators = new HashMap<>();
    healthIndicators.put("solr1", createHealthIndicator(firstHttpSolrClient()));
    healthIndicators.put("solr2", createHealthIndicator(secondHttpSolrClient()));
    healthIndicators.put("querySolr", createHealthIndicator(queryHttpSolrClient()));

    return new CompositeHealthIndicator(this.healthAggregator, healthIndicators);
}
```